# Zero over zero converges to what

Tags: calculus

Quick question.

What is the result of $lim_{x \to 0} y(x) = lim_{x \to 0} (- {2x \over 3x})$  ?

I am struggling to understand what 0 over 0 goes to...

If someone could tell me what the result is and possibly provide an explanation, that would be very helpful)

Comment: $$x\to0\implies x\ne0$$

Comment: While $x\neq 0$, you can cancel.

Comment: Remember that you do not care what actually happens at the point $x=0$ You only care about what happens nearby.

Comment: These are all very helpful comments. Thank you! :)

Comment: THanks to those who responded. I don't understand why this question was voted down! Do people only have to publish original research questions on this website?

Comment: I think it was voted down because maybe you showed no effort in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can can't cancel with 0's then just apply l'hopital's rule and you'll simply get that the limit is $-2/3$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is simply $\frac{-2}{3}$. As suggested in the comments when $x$ is not zero you can cancel them, leaving the fraction $-2/3$. But, to understand why its -2/3, its useful to see what a limit implies. As such,
$$\frac{-2}{3} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$$
As $x$ approaches to zero, the numerator and denominator approach it at the same rate(exluding $-2/3$ which can easily be taken out of the limit). For example, if $x=0.0001$ which is very close to zero is placed in the fraction then we have $0.0001/0.0001=1$. Using the similar idea for numbers closer to zero, the limit will always be one.